# index.php doesn't show header or footer only on first call

Tags: php, html, include

strange problem: on the first call of my test homepage http://risklantern.eu/index.php, it doesn't show either header or footer (and sometimes just not the header). Here's the code:

```
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
       <?php include ("/titlebar.inc"); ?>
       <main id="content">
            Main page goes here
       </main>
       <?php include ("/footer.inc"); ?>
    </div>
 </body>
```

If I instead call http://risklantern.eu/blog and then click on home, which also calls index.php in the main directory, the page looks as it should.
I first suspected it was a directory problem, so I inserted getcwd call at various points, but it is always at the directory where it should be. Plus, it runs fine on my XAMPP locally, the behavior is only on the online server.

Anybody encounter something like this before?

Comment: those paths are probably wrong. include works at the file system level, so you're trying to include files from the root of your filesystem, not the document root of your site. the only exception would be is if your site is running inside a chroot jail...

Comment: @MarcB I do wonder how it would work locally. I mean he probably hasn't  put the site in his root of his file-system, or does it have to be?

Comment: try using `require` instead of `include` and it will at least die properly with some debug info, also use `__DIR__`

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you've stated. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: ok, it looks as though the server sets the include_path to a strange value - I'll put a set_include_path in and see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include path, beginning with slash `/` indicates the root, so in this case I bet that is your hard disk root. Try to assign your real document root to a variable and use it with includes or requires:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include ($root."/titlebar.inc");
```

Obviously, `titlebar.inc` must be in your current project root.

Comment: That was it - thanks!
NB: actually, the include_path was at a subdirectory of htdocs, not sure why XAMPP and the Strato server behaved differently there, though. Oh well, fixed :-)

Comment: You are welcome  I am not sure what is the reason, anyway the server has to have a root, the hard disk root looks accesible and easy to manage. Anyway you can create include paths to solve it if you need it. Take a look to **[this page](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html)** for more information.